# Can I check whether a file has been updated in Sharepoint as an ADF trigger?

Tags: azure-data-factory, oracle-adf

I want to setup a ADF pipeline so that when a specific excel file is edited and saved in sharepoint, on the next pipeline run (24 hour trigger), a pipeline will execute ONLY if the file has been edited/updated.

Is there any straight forward way to set this up in ADF?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Sharepoint REST API to get the details of the files last modifieddt.

REST API: _api/web/Lists/GetByTitle('')/Items?$select=FileLeafRef,FileRef,ID,%20Title,Created,Modified,Editor/Title,Content_x0020_Owner/Title,File_x0020_Type&$expand=Editor,Content_x0020_Owner&$top=50000`

Similar : https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/284207/how-to-get-sharepoint-files-properties-by-rest-api

And you can compare that value with the last successful run and in case if that value is greater than the last successful run, then proceed further and do preserve the date value at the end.

If not, then skip the further activities and escape the pipeline run.

The above architecture is assuming only ADF pipelines are being used.

Else you can use a logic app to do the comparisons and trigger the ADF at the end if the conditions meet